# Create and Index in same view using partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok I give up after several hours of troubleshooting, but I am sure you all will see a solution right away. I have three models Person, Course and CoursePreference. The CoursePreference model has two foreign keys PersonId and CourseId.

What I want to do:
I want to create a view where the user can add course preferences in a top Create section, and when they click Add, the form would post and refresh the List in the same view. Essentially I am combining Index and Create in one view. So I created an Index View and a partial view called _CreatePartial in the CoursePreference folder.

The problem:
The view displays fine, but with two problems. 1) The CoursePreferenceId field shows a dropdownlist. I want it to be a hidden field since it's an identity. I copied the code exactly from the scaffolded Create View, which hides the Id correctly. Dont know why it's not working in the _CreatePartial view? 2) Most importantly, my _CreatePartial will not add any course preference. It looks as if the form is posting but no record is added.

What gives?

Here are the models, controllers and views:

```
---------------------------
Models (stripped down versions)
---------------------------


public class CoursePreference
{
public int CoursePreferenceId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> CourseId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PersonId { get; set; }
public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
public int PersonId { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<CoursePreference> CoursePreferences { get; set; }    
}

public class Course
{
public int CourseId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ProgramId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<CoursePreference> CoursePreferences { get; set; }
}

------------------
Controllers
------------------

public ActionResult _CreatePartial()
{
ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name");
ViewBag.PersonId = new SelectList(db.People, "PersonId", "LastName");
return View("_CreatePartial");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name");
ViewBag.PersonId = new SelectList(db.People, "PersonId", "LastName");
var coursepreferences = db.CoursePreferences.Include(c => c.Course).Include(c => c.Person);
return View(coursepreferences.ToList());
}

---------------------------
Index View
---------------------------

@model IEnumerable<MyProj.Models.CoursePreference>

@{  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h4>Add Course Preferences</h4>

<div>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/CoursePreference/_CreatePartial.cshtml", new MyProj.Models.CoursePreference())
</div>
<br />
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Course.Name)
</th>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.LastName)
</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Name)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.LastName)
</td>
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CoursePreferenceId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CoursePreferenceId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CoursePreferenceId })
</td>
</tr>
}

</table>
---------------------------
_CreatePartial View
---------------------------

@model MyProj.Models.CoursePreference

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>CoursePreference</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoursePreferenceId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CoursePreferenceId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoursePreferenceId)
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "CourseId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId)
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonId, "PersonId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("PersonId", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonId)
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is saved because you don't have a controller method to handle the post. Implement this in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CoursePreference pref)
{
    // Insert code to fetch database context into variable "db"
    db.CoursePreferences.Add(pref);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

As for the hidden ID-field, you should use:

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CoursePreferenceId)`

-not `EditorFor` or `LabelFor`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed both the Save and the hidden field issue. I had incorrectly put my POST code in the Partial View. I was under the impression that the Partial view does the job of inserting the new record as well, when in fact the Index view/controller do the db.Object.Add. Stackoverflow rocks.